# React callback undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have this React Component written in ts which renders another component 
which takes items and OnItemRender as props.When AnotherComponent renders each item it calls the itemrender. This is working fine and i am getting the textboxes displayed for every item .Now i have attached an onChange Eventhandler for every textbox. 
But on any change on textbox i am getting a console error . `this` is undefined.

Since i am using arrow functions i think the `this` should be bound to lexical scope correctly . I have even tried adding `this.handleChange =` `this.handleChange.bind(this)` but error remains the same. What am i doing wrong?

```
class MyNewList extends React.Component<any, any> {

  public render(){
    return (
      <AnotherComponent  items = {this.state.items } onItemRender = {this.itemRender}
    )
  }

  public itemRender(item,column){
    return (
        <input type="text" value={this.state.value} 
         onChange= {(event) => this.handleChange(event,item)} />
    )
  }

  public handleChange(event,item){

  }
}
```

Comment: did you bind `itemRender` method?? like this: `this.itemRender = this.itemRender.bind(this)` ?

Comment: There's just x,y arguments and you're showing us .....args... which may mislead us. Show actual code for its readability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the itemRender is the one that is losing the scope. Try binding the itemRender method instead of the handleChange method.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need of binding the handleChange method, since you're calling it inside of the itemRender method,
but you do need to bind the itemRender method.

try this

```
class MyNewList extends React.Component<any, any> {

    public render(){
        return (
        <AnotherComponent  items = {this.state.items } onItemRender = {this.itemRender.bind(this)}
        )
    }

    public itemRender(item,column){
        return (
            <input type="text" value={this.state.value} 
            onChange= {(event) => this.handleChange(event,item)} />
        )
    }

    public handleChange(event,item){

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try :) This should work.

```
class MyNewList extends React.Component<any, any> {

  public render(){
    return (
      <AnotherComponent  items = {this.state.items } 
      onItemRender = {
        (event) => this.itemRender(
          event, this.state.item, this.state.column)
      }
    )
  }

  public itemRender(event, item, column){
    return (
        <input type="text" value={this.state.value} 
         onChange= {this.handleChange(event, item, column)} />
    )
  }

  public handleChange(event, item, column){

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it -- rely on a DOM attribute like this:

```
 class MyNewList extends React.Component<any, any> {
     public constructor(props) {
         super(props);
         this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
     }

     public render() {
         return (
             <AnotherComponent
                 items={this.state.items}
                 onItemRender={this.itemRender} />
         )
     }

     public itemRender(item, column) {
         return (
             <input
                 type="text" value={this.state.value}
                 name={item.name}
                 onChange={this.handleChange} />
         )
     }

     public handleChange(e){
         const name = e.target.name;
         console.log(name, 'changed');
     }
 }
```